# OpenLDAP Access Control Issue

Tags: linux, openldap

I need guidance in below situation - 
I am migrating RHDS to openLDAP. I managed to convert the DIT and their attributes and Schemas. However, I am stuck at Access control.

In RHDS, currently, the access control is as below -

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: aci
aci: (target = ldap:///uid=*,ou=household,dc=example,dc=com) (targetattr="*") (version 3.0; acl "Household Itms Consumer subtree read - aci"; allow (read, compare, search) (userdn = "ldap:///*,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com") ;);
```

Could some please guide me in creating the OLC LDIF format?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Access control is not part of the LDAPv3 standard and thus attribute *aci* is specific to *RHDS* and similar implementations.

You have to define new ACLs for your OpenLDAP setup.

I'd recommend to read the following docs:

- [OpenLDAP Admin Guide -- Access control](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)
- [slapd.access(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.access)
- [FAQ-O-MATIC: Access Control](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/189.html)
- [FAQ-O-MATIC: Sets in Access Control](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1133.html)